# ORM classes ending with letter "s" are not generated properly

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sqlacodegen

I'm using SQLAlchemy and [sqlacodegen](https://pypi.org/project/sqlacodegen/) to generate ORM classes for my PostgreSQL models. But to my surprise, tables ending with letter "s" are causing issue.

For example, I have a table as below

```
employee_status
```

and the ORM class generated for this table is as below

```
Class EmployeeStatu(Base):
    __tablename__ = "employee_status"
    col1 = Column(String(32))
```

Why is the ending letter "s" missing in class name when it is present in table name?

Comment: looks like the bug, but may be the author of the utility you use try to generate python class in the singular.

Comment: Most likely it has to do with pluralization of table names. Check how to configure pluralization for SQLAlchemy.

Comment: https://github.com/agronholm/sqlacodegen#model-class-naming-logic read the section `Model class naming logic`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sqlacodegen [doesn't do this itself](https://pypi.org/project/sqlacodegen/#model-class-naming-logic):

> **Model class naming logic**
>
> The table name (which is assumed to be in English) is converted to singular form using the "inflect" library. Then, every underscore is removed while transforming the next letter to upper case. For example, `sales_invoices` becomes `SalesInvoice`.

This appears to have [already been reported as a bug in that library](https://github.com/jazzband/inflect/issues/15#issuecomment-218737160). In the meantime nothing is stopping you from correcting the class name manually.